# как изменить значения таймера

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Есть веб-приложение для игры в баре. У него есть таймер обратного отсчета, который показывает пользователям, сколько времени осталось до конца игры.

timer.js

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  return {
    'total': t,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
} 
  
function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('#hh');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('#mm');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('#ss');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }
 
  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline="October 07 2021 21:20:00 GMT+0300"; // точная дата
initializeClock('countdown', deadline);
```

вопрос в том, как я могу изменить значение «deadline» (скажем, из админки), не перезагружая вручную файл timer.js на сервер?

Comment: а как сейчас заменить дедлайн на клиенте, «не перезагружая вручную файл timer.js на сервер»?

Comment: @nörbörnën в том и суть что без перезагрузки файла на сервер изменить его никак, а мне нужно как то  что бы я мог добавить или отнять время таймера из админки для всех пользователей. Я никак не могу придумать как это реализовать(((

Comment: я имел ввиду, что показ таймера сейчас инкапсулирован так, что никакое внешнее воздействие с ним не возможно. а по задаче: ну, сделайте фиксацию начала "игры" на бэкенд и websocket-ом присылайте раз в секунду структурку типа той, что возвращает getTimeRemaining. если дедлайн будет на бекенде тогда и редактировать его становится возможным

Comment: спасибо буду пробовать